# API CALL ERROR curl_setopt_array(): Cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, guzzle

I keep getting this error when I try to make an API call on my laravel App. v8

```
$uploadedImage = $request->image->store('watermark');
$photo = fopen($uploadedImage, 'r');

$response = Http::withHeaders([
        'content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ])->withOptions([
        'debug' => true,
    ])->attach(
        'image', $photo, $uploadedImage
    )->post('http://dummyapiwebsite.com/');
```

dd($response)

Comment: A bit of research suggest that this might be due to `'debug' => true`. https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug: _“If set to true, the output is written to PHP's STDOUT”_ - but that appears to go wrong here for some reason.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply, i'm still getting a response of "Bad request" from GuzzleHttp when I remove the debug option

Comment: Well that’s a completely separate issue. Your request is faulty in some way, and not exactly how the remote part wants it to be. Caught between a rock and a hard place a bit here probably, because you might need debug information, to figure out what’s wrong with your request. Try to pass a pointer to a file opened with `fopen()` for `debug`, and see if you can find useful info in that file then afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uploadedImage = $request->image->store('watermark');
$photo = fopen($uploadedImage, 'r');

$response = Http::attach(
        'image', $photo, $uploadedImage
    )->post('http://dummyapiwebsite.com/')->json();
```